# How to edit each <img> size in string variable (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to edit image size (width & height) in the string variable but I need to edit it by Regex expression to take its width and height and then divide it by 2.

In Example:

I have images in a string variable

```js
const html = `<p><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F1cb%2F1cb8a6aa-8dbf-4cc1-90ae-e214d46eb4c1%2Fphp7FkMW8.png"style="height:34px;width:158px;" /></p><p><strong>explanation:</strong></p><p><strong><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F7f8%2F7f87506b-9fb5-421f-85e6-b283732266d2%2FphprAsgze.png"style="height:130px;width:387px;" /></strong></p>`
```

As you can see, there are two img tags in this variable.

The first image size is: `(height:34px;width:158px;)`.

The second image size is: `height:130px;width:387px;`.

Now, I need to edit the first and the second image size to take its half size

Example to edit 34px height: 34/2 = 17
and the same for the width...

So, the new size of height is: 17px
then replace the new size with its CSS style

The final result should be like this:

```js
const HTMl = `<p><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F1cb%2F1cb8a6aa-8dbf-4cc1-90ae-e214d46eb4c1%2Fphp7FkMW8.png"style="height:17px;width:79px;" /></p><p><strong>explanation:</strong></p><p><strong><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F7f8%2F7f87506b-9fb5-421f-85e6-b283732266d2%2FphprAsgze.png"style="height:65px;width:193.5px;" /></strong></p>`
```

i hope it's clear what i need. you can do it by regex or any method that can do what i need.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before set it to const `HTMl` variable, you can create variables for the height and width of the imgs.

```
const firstImgWidth = 158;
const secondImgWidth = 387;
const firstImgHeight = 34;
const secondImgHeight = 130;
```

Then you can interpolate these variables with Template Strings, [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const html = `<p><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F1cb%2F1cb8a6aa-8dbf-4cc1-90ae-e214d46eb4c1%2Fphp7FkMW8.png"style="height:${firstImgHeight}px;width:${firstImgWidth}px;" /></p><p><strong>explanation:</strong></p><p><strong><img alt="" src="https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F7f8%2F7f87506b-9fb5-421f-85e6-b283732266d2%2FphprAsgze.png"style="height:${secondImgHeight}px;width:${secondImgWidth}px;" /></strong></p>
```

This way, you will be able to manipulate your `<imgs>` attributes easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
But what when I have more than an image (i.e 5 images).
it's not fine to declare new variables that take the new size of the image.
I think it's fine to edit infinite image size in the string variable by regex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it’s possible you should look at the document objects rich functionality. MDN has some good documentation on it. A good document property to start with is `document.createElement`.